# How can I sort objects by the value of one of the keys

Tags: node.js, json, object

So I've been trying to sort the following object and ive been having some trouble:

```
let obj = {
 "1": {
  "name": "card1",
  "ryo": 3
},
"2": {
  "name": "card2",
  "ryo": 7
},
 "3": {
  "name": "card3",
  "ryo": 2
  }
}

Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((x, y) => y[1].ryo - x[1].ryo));
```

The code above returns:

```
{
  '1': { name: 'card1', ryo: 3 },
  '2': { name: 'card2', ryo: 7 },
  '3': { name: 'card3', ryo: 2 }
}
```

my goal is to get it to return:

```
{
  '2': { name: 'card2', ryo: 7 },
  '1': { name: 'card1', ryo: 3 },
  '3': { name: 'card3', ryo: 2 }
}
```

As simple as it seems I just cant get it to work and I dont know why it wont sort.

Edit: Id like to add that im trying to sort the object by ryo in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting to an array then sorting like this

```
let sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
return b[1].ryo - a[1].ryo
});
```

Comment: As this sorts it, it leaves me with an array and when I use Object.fromEntries() it converts back to its original object which is not sorted :(

Comment: @MeowGuy
who exactly are you?
Tyron Ghhl?